# JSON Dictionary to Core Data

Tags: iphone, rest, core-data, restkit, key-value

I have a JSON response that I turn into a Dictionary like so:

```
NSError *error;
self.restKitResponseDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response.body options:0 error:&error]];
```

I have a core data class that has the following attributes/properties:

```
name
image_url
```

When I log the `restKitResponseDict` from above I see that `image_url` is listed as `"image_url"` like this:

```
name = Rock;
"image_url" = "http://f.cl.ly/items/122s3f1M1E1p432B211Q/catstronaut.jpg";
```

Is this why KVC is crashing on

`[CoreDataClass setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:self.restKitResponseDict];`

like this:

```
'[<CoreDataClass 0x14132c> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image_url.'
```

Do the quotes matter? Should I ask my server guy to get rid of the underscore that's likely causing it?

Core Data Class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface CoreDataClass : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * image_url;

@end

@implementation CoreDataClass

@dynamic name;
@dynamic image_url;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the method to the class object:

```
[CoreDataClass setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:self.restKitResponseDict];
```

when you probably want to send it to the actual CoreDataClass instance:

```
[coreDataClassObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:self.restKitResponseDict];
```

**EDIT**

> what's the simplest way to init the object from the class? – Eric

It's a subclass of NSManagedObject, so you use the normal Core Data methods.  One way to create a new object:

```
CoreDataClass *coreDataObject = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"YOUR_ENTITY_NAME"
    inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

If you need basic information about using Core Data, see the Core Data Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1

Comment: what's the simplest way to init the object from the class?

Answer (score 1):

The `NSLog()` with the `%@` format uses the `description` method to print objects, and the description of a `NSDictionary` puts quotation marks around all keys and values that contain any special characters, such as the underscore. For example

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"key1" : @"value_1",
    @"key_2" : @"value2"
};
NSLog(@"dict=%@", dict);
```

produces

```
2012-08-25 18:15:33.553 test27[3416:c07] dict={
    key1 = "value_1";
    "key_2" = value2;
}
```

Therefore the key in your JSON dictionary does not really have quotation marks, and the underscore is probably not the cause of the error.

The error message indicates that the managed object does *not* have an `image_url` attribute, therefore you should check that.